# Django - accessing modelform field value in template

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form with multiple fields, one of which I would like to be able to replace the field's HTML control with just the plain text of the field's value.  What do I do in the template, in models.py, or in my forms.py to do this?  I have nothing in my forms.py related to that field yet, just other fields.

```
#models.py
class RoomEvent(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey('Room')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

-

```
#template 
<form method='POST' action=''>

<table>
    <tr>
<td><label for="id_room">Room:</label></td> 
<td>{{ form.room.room.name }}</td>
</tr>
...
```

I have tried this:

```
#fields.py:
class RoomEventForm(ModelForm):
    room = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Room.objects.select_related())
```

...then replacing `{{form.room}}` with `{{form.room.room.name}}` in the template, to no avail.  Just gives me a blank.

`{{ form.room.name }}` gives me "room"..?

`{{ form.room.value }}` gives me the ID, not the actual name.

Why is this so difficult???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using `{{ roomevent.room.name }}` where `roomevent` is the ModelForm's model.  I guess that's the "generally accepted" way of doing this.